# Static IP configuration on openSUSE

Tags: networking, opensuse, ip

I'm tasked with configuring a static IP network in Linux openSUSE 11.3 (32-bit, a discontinued release I believe), for which OS I'm doing this for the first time. I need to configure the network taking the following expectations into consideration:

- network is part of the `192.168.146.0/24` domain,
- network must support at least **21** clients,
- subnet uses as little of the original network as possible.

After doing the calculations, this comes down to the following bitmask:

```
110nnnnn.nnnnnnnn.nnnnnnnn.ssshhhhh
```

Where of course `n` network, `s` is subnet, `h` is host. This supports 30 hosts per subnet which is adequate, and from which the following subnets span:

1. 192.168.146.0 - 192.168.146.31
2. 192.168.146.32 - 192.168.146.63
3. 192.168.146.64 - 192.168.146.95
4. **192.168.146.96 - 192.168.146.127**
5. ...

I need to configure the network to use the **3rd** *usable* subnet, and for the host I'm configuring this network on, to use the lowest possible IP address from that subnet (`192.168.146.97`, I believe). The network interface is `eth0`, and this is an internal network.

I'm certain either `ifconfig` or the `ifcfg-eth0` file is what I need, but documentation is either sketchy, meant solely as a reference for linux experts, or just not where I should look at. I'm using the built-in Terminal window, and I of course have root access.

---

Long-story short, how can I configure the network so that:

- the host I'm doing the configuration on has the static IP of `192.168.146.97`, and
- the network is `192.168.146.96` - `192.168.146.127`?

Comment: `ifconfig` will work, but the settings will be lost after reboot. If this is just an academic exercise, that's fine, but you'd normally use [`yast`](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_yast.html) to set things up and store the result into files, and you'd also specify a *default gateway*, the address of another system on the network to use as the gateway to the rest of your organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you need to make or edit is called `ifcfg <interface>`, where `<interface>`
could be e.g. `eth0` or `eth1`.

On Freebsd and Debian I used :`ifconfig <interface> <ip address> <netmask>` and it worked please try it.

Comment: Indeed it [does](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280560/168466), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I thought, this is possible using `ifconfig`. On the host being configured, type:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.146.97 netmask 255.255.255.224
```

Comment: This is only going to affect the run-time configuration. You need to edit the files underneath `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` (in this case `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`) This file is read when the system is booted or the "network" service is restarted.

Comment: @Bratchles Yes, you are right. In the end, I resorted to using yast, which provided a surprisingly convenient GUI for configuration. I believe it is writing to this same file when changes are made.

Comment: yeah `yast2` is definitely the tool to use if you're a novice. You'll want to learn how to do things the normal way but yast is an excellent example of training wheels.

Answer (score 0):

I've done all the above, but still nobody can connect, and upon investigation I find that it has reverted back to a dynamic ip assigned by the modem (according to ifconfig,) and `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0` still contains the static ip:

```
# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

`ifcfg-eth0` file:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='192.168.1.200'
MTU='1500'
NAME=''
NETMASK='255.255.255.0'
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
ZONE=public
USERCONTROL='no'
```

Yast also shows the ip as static 192.168.1.200, but ifconfig says it's dynamic.  What's going on, ho can I fix this?